# Laravel api route class to found error

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel-5.3

I'm currently working on api jwt based authentication off a boiler plate on SitePoint.  So far I've gotten everything working but I'm stuck on this point.

My Controller looks like this:

```
namespace App\Api\V1\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use JWTAuth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Order;
// use App\Api\V1\Requests\LoginRequest;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
```

in the body I have this function:

```
  public function checkThis()
  {
    $currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $orders = App\Order::first();
    echo $orders;
    function() {
    echo "stll here";
    };
  }
```

Under my api route I have this in a middleware:

```
$api->get('orderlist', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\OrderController@checkThis');
```

When I run this in postman I get the following error: "message": "Class 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\App\Order' not found",

I've tried everything I can think of and it still keeps happening.  When I take it out of the controller and run it directly in the routes it works.  I'm a newbie to Laravel and PHP so I'm kinda of stuck.

Comment: $orders = \App\Order::first();   try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thing below assusing that you want to invoke the **App\Order::first();**

In function **checkThis** , you can replace  **App\Order::first()**  by

> Order::first()   //aliasing version

or  replace  **App\Order::first()**  by

> \App\Order::first();    //fully qualified Name version

By [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

```
Example #1 importing/aliasing with the use operator
<?php
namespace foo;
use My\Full\Classname as Another;

// this is the same as use My\Full\NSname as NSname   <-- very important 
use My\Full\NSname;
```

**Notice that**

```
// this is the same as use My\Full\NSname as NSname   <-- very important 
    use My\Full\NSname;
```

[another php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)

> and Inside a namespace, when PHP encounters an unqualified Name in a
>   class name, function or constant context, it resolves these with
>   different priorities. Class names always resolve to the current
>   namespace name. Thus to access internal or non-namespaced user
>   classes, one **must refer to them with their fully qualified Name**

[php manual : fully qualified Name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)

> Fully qualified name
>
> This is an identifier with a namespace separator that begins with a namespace separator, such as \Foo\Bar. The namespace \Foo is also a
>   fully qualified name.

So if you want to invoke the function   **App\Order**::first ,just **Order::first**,**for the reason that**

```
use App\Order;     
equal 
use App\Order as Order ;
```

the aliasing is **Order** instead of  **App\Order**  . And the **Fully qualified name**  is  **\App\Order** instead of **App\Order**.

On the other hand , when you  invoke **App\Order::first();**
it means that you are invoking

```
App\Api\V1\Controllers\App\Order::first();
```

So it can't not find the class;

Here is my demo

file1.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
class  Order{
public static function   first(){
echo "i am first";
  }
}
```

file2.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Api\V1\Controllers;
include 'file1.php';

use App\Order ;
\App\Order::first();
// and you can do it by 
//  Order::first();  they are equal in this place
```

when i  run  command **php file2.php**
it echo **i am first**